# How to dynamically change color of xml/rss tag generated in PHP

Tags: php, xml, rss

I want to change color of all content in given tag in xml/rss file generated using PHP.

What i did (and it didnt worked):

```
//create "description" node under "item"
  $description_node = $item_node->appendChild($xml->createElement("description"));  
  if($row->end_time >= time()) { //row->en_time contains unix timestamp, it was extracted from database
    $description_node->SetAttribute("color","red");
  } elseif ($row->end_time < time()) {
          $description_node->SetAttribute("color","black");
  }
```

How to do it?

XML file is generated properly. Thats how tag  looks like:

```
<description color="red">
  <![CDATA[ 07:00 - 13:30 Sala 5 ]]>
</description>
```

Maybe the problem is color="red"? Shouldn't it be

```
  <description style=color:"red">
```

Comment: no that is the correct behavior, thats how an xml attribute should be. the other example you have is an html element attribute

Comment: If it is correct - it is not working for me...